# Vue JS - Hide or remove duplicates in child component field

Tags: vue.js

I have a child component and it has one field which pulls in repeating data from an Axios request.

**Displays** Name: blue, blue, red, orange, green, green, blue

**Child**

```
 <div v-if="color">
                <strong> Color:</strong> {{ color }}
              </div>

data: function () {
    return {
      color: this.result.color
}
```

**Parent**

```
<Result
              v-for="(result, index) in Results"
              :result="result"                      
             
            />
```

**JSON**

```
"result": [
"results": {
"color": "Blue, Green, Red", 
},
"results": {
"color": "Blue", 
},
"results": {
"color": "Red", 
},
"results": {
"color": "Green, Red", 
},
.....
```

How can I remove the duplicates? I have tried using a method/computed but I could get it to work. I tried a computed prop on the parent and passing it but it messed up other results on the parent.
Would a mutation be better? I want to do this on the child component and not on the parent if possible.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In child, You can filtered out the duplicate `colors` with the help of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object.

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('result', {
  data() {
    return {
        color: null
    }
  },
  props: ['result'],
  mounted() {
    this.color = [...new Set(this.result.color)];
  },
  template: '<p>{{ color }}</p>'
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    Results: [{
        color: ['blue', 'blue', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'green', 'blue']
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <Result v-for="(result, index) in Results" :key="index" :result="result">
  </Result>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful indeed. It has reduced the data. Howerver now each entry is displayed like this: Name: [ "G", "R", "E", "E", "N", "," ] or Name: [ "B", "L", "U", "E", "" ]  etc. What is going on! :)

Comment: Can I also ask why this new Set is in a mounted function and does not work as a computed property or method? Thank you @Rohìt Jíndal

Comment: can you please confirm is that `Results` is containing same data format as per my code snippet ? or it is like an array of objects `[{color: 'blue'}, {color: 'green'}, ...]`  ?

Comment: I added this in a mounted like cycle hook as it invoked as soon as component mounted.

Comment: I have added part of the JSON file to my original question. Thanks for taking the time to help with this.